# CS0121 :: Why the method call is ambigous between identical methods/namespaces and signatures? .NET 8 + CommunityToolkit

Tags: winui-3

The error is being detected between two identical signatures :

[image]

I try to use this extnasion method from the Community Toolkit:

```
using Microsoft.UI.Dispatching;

#if WINDOWS
using CommunityToolkit.WinUI;
#endif


#if WINDOWS
                dispatcherQueue.EnqueueAsync(() => _eventAggregator.GetEvent<AppEventEvent>().Publish(e), DispatcherQueuePriority.Normal);
#endif
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the 8.0 packages, it could be a compatibility issue. I suggest you could refer to the thread: https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Windows/issues/277

Refer to the blog: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/ifdef-windows/windows-community-toolkit-8-0-pre-release/

> Note: Mixing and matching these new 8.0 packages with existing Windows
> Community Toolkit 7.x packages, especially UI controls, can lead to
> issues with the namespace changes and dependencies on common code
> (like the Visual Tree extensions).

Comment: Thank you. You were right, Uno/WinUI 3 projects shall phase out CommunityToolkit.WinUI 7.1 packages.

Comment: Have you got any updates about this issue? If your case has been solved, please help to mark answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Comment: Thank you. Now I marked your answer as solution. Though the package `CommunityToolkit.WinUI.UI 8.0` not yet appeared even as pre released nuget package.